# possible to generate qr code using only bitcoin core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, qrcode

Bitcoin core qt generates a qr code. Can I do it with the json rpc or by some other means without using 3rd party libs? Right now, I'm using a 3rd party lib and it's working; just trying to tighten things up if possible (with licenses, dependencies and maintainability).

I'm not looking to reverse engineer C code to do it; that would be overkill for the benefit probably.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QR Code creation is a GUI only thing. You cannot create a QR code without using the GUI. The JSON-RPC interface only works for text based things and cannot trigger GUI actions.

Comment: ok I see the QR Code has nothing to do with bitcoin. It's just a flexible bar code system. Since I'm in php I found a library phpqrcode to do the job.